# Converting raw data into long format

Tags: count, stata, long-integer

I am importing data that is neither long nor wide:

```
clear

input str1 id purchased sold
A 2017 .
B . .
C 2016 2019
C 2018 .
D 2018 2019
D 2018 .
end
```

My goal is to get the data in the following long format, reflecting the count in each year:

```
Identifier Year Inventory
     A     2016     0
     A     2017     1
     A     2018     1
     A     2019     1
     B     2016     0
     B     2017     0
     B     2018     0
     B     2019     0
     C     2016     1
     C     2017     1
     C     2018     2
     C     2019     1
     D     2016     0
     D     2017     0
     D     2018     2
     D     2019     1
```

My initial approach would be to transform it first into a wide format, that is having only one row per identifier, and adding columns for years between 2016-2018. And then converting this format into the desired long format. However, this seems to be inefficient.

Is there any shorter and more efficient method to do this, as I have a much larger dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs several small tricks. The most crucial are `reshape long` and `fillin`. 
The inventory is essentially a running sum of purchases minus sales.

```
clear
input str1 Identifier  Purchased  Sold 
A   2017    .
B   .   .
C   2016    2019
C   2018    .
D   2018    2019
D   2018    .
end 

generate long id = _n 
rename (Purchased Sold) year= 
reshape long year, i(id) j(Event) string 
drop id 

fillin Id year 
drop _fillin 
drop if missing(year) 

bysort Id (year Event) : generate inventory = sum((Event == "Purchased") - (Event == "Sold")) 
drop Event 
bysort Id year : keep if _n == _N 
list, sepby(Id) 

     +----------------------------+
     | Identi~r   year   invent~y |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |        A   2016          0 |
  2. |        A   2017          1 |
  3. |        A   2018          1 |
  4. |        A   2019          1 |
     |----------------------------|
  5. |        B   2016          0 |
  6. |        B   2017          0 |
  7. |        B   2018          0 |
  8. |        B   2019          0 |
     |----------------------------|
  9. |        C   2016          1 |
 10. |        C   2017          1 |
 11. |        C   2018          2 |
 12. |        C   2019          1 |
     |----------------------------|
 13. |        D   2016          0 |
 14. |        D   2017          0 |
 15. |        D   2018          2 |
 16. |        D   2019          1 |
     +----------------------------+
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks - learning a few more commands here. I have one more follow on question. Let's pretend, that I replace one of the "Purchase"-years with 2001, e.g. for C. When I see it correctly, the 'fillin' command won't fill up all the years between numbers, but only the years that actually occured in the initial dataset.

My workaround would be to add rows in the form of a placeholder ID for each of the years that are of interest for me (or are between Min and Max), and then dropping that ID afterwards. This however feels quite unsophisticated - is there a more efficient way?

Comment: That’s what I would do.

Comment: https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0011 says a little more.